# A video player that auto-plays videos in sequence while skipping certain parts

Tags: video, script, vlc-media-player, automation

There is a TV show I like; I have its episodes stored as video files on my SSD. Each video file is about 24 minutes long, but only 20 minutes of that is the actual episode; the rest is intro, outro, recap, etc.

I would like to binge-watch about 7-8 episodes in a row, but I'm tired of having to manually start each video file and skip the non-episode parts. Is there a video player that would allow me to define a playing schedule, specifically:

- which files are played and in what order,
- which parts of each file are skipped.

That would allow me to have a more seamless viewing experience. I could also share the schedule (which would ideally be a text file), so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm asking how to perform an advanced operation for video playback. Where can I ask such a question if not here?

Comment: Read my previous comment. It tells you exactly where to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't found a solution like what you're looking for, but [this vlc add-on designed to skip radio ads](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/Online+Radio+AD+Blocker?content=160542) might be a good place to start. It may be easily editable to fit your needs (especially if you have experience with basic programming.) Good Luck!